# Python class Attribute Error even though attribute is in __init__

Tags: python, class, attributeerror, python-3.10, ursina

I'm trying to run my program:

```py
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

app = Ursina()
window.fullscreen = True

class Voxel(Button):
    def __init__(self, colour, position = (0, 0, 0)):
        super().__init__(
            parent  = scene,
            position = position,
            model = "cube",
            orgin_y = 0.5,
            texture = "white_cube",
            color = colour,
            )

    def start_game(self):
        self.colour = color.white

    def input(self, key):
        if self.hovered:
            if key == "right mouse up":
                voxel = Voxel(position = self.position + mouse.normal, colour = self.colour)

            if key == "left mouse up":
                destroy(self)

            if key == "0":
                self.colour = color.white

            if key == "1":
                self.colour = color.lime

for z in range(22):
    for x in range(22):
        voxel = Voxel(position = (x, 0, z), colour = color.lime)
        voxel.start_game()

player = FirstPersonController()
app.run()
```

I'm using python 3.10.6 and Idle.

When I run the program it works as expected except when I choose green after I place a block it turn into white. If I spam click I get the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\game.py", line 24, in input
    voxel = Voxel(position = self.position + mouse.normal, colour = self.colour)
AttributeError: 'Voxel' object has no attribute 'colour'
```

Comment: `Voxel.start_game` and `Voxel.input` set the `colour` attribute. Are you sure `Button.__init__` doesn't define a `color` attribute?

Comment: Also, it's not clear when you are calling `Voxel.input`, but it would appear to be before you ever call `Voxel.start_game`.

Answer (score 2):

This code appears to be using both `color` and `colour` in multiple places.

It looks like the [`ursina` library uses the `color` form](https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/blob/3181f08f7a520349d52d62d557026cc2e66eb989/ursina/prefabs/button.py#L6-L28).

I would suggest using `color` everywhere in your code to stay consistent with the library you are using.  It will be harder to maintain if you need to translate between spellings and remember which version is used in which place.

Additionally, even though their examples may use `from ursina import *`, [it is not the best practice to do so](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports) because it makes it unclear what names are available in the namespace.  It would be better to explicitly do `from ursina import Ursina, Button, window`.

Answer (score 0):

You are using colour instead of color when using self.colour and also when calling Voxel.

You should do:

`voxel = Voxel(position = self.position + mouse.normal, colour = self.color)`

And:

`self.color = color`

The solution is to replace colour with color in your code.